# Where should I place viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner with Data Binding and Lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

The following code is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

I'm not sure where I should place `viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner` between `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()`, could you tell me?

```
class TasksFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewDataBinding: TasksFragBinding  

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewDataBinding = TasksFragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        //viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner    Can I place here?
        return viewDataBinding.root
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        // Set the lifecycle owner to the lifecycle of the view
        viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner    
    }

   ..
}
```

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is deprecated. You should use `onViewCreated` or `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 2):

`onActivityCreated` is deprecated. You should use `onViewCreated` or `onCreateView`.

```
private var binding: TasksFragBinding? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val viewDataBinding = TasksFragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
        viewmodel = viewModel
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    }
    this.binding = viewDataBinding 

    return viewDataBinding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
}
```

Comment: So it doesn't matter which override you use? I like what you did with the apply method. I need a similiar thing in my problem I think - I have 1 fragment that can keep recreating itself (nested menus). But I need to share the same viewmodel between them all using activityViewModels. I'm nearly there with it, but I'm just trying to workout if I have to set the viewmodel and lifecycleOwner every time in the recreated fragment.

Comment: tbh it's pretty rare to need `activityViewModels` at all, what people generally wanted is to have a parent fragment that has child fragments, and scope to the parent fragment